# cutting sheet metal on K3 board

Tags: cutting

I have about 16 school chalkboards 4 ft. by 8 ft. made of sheet metal laminated to 1/2" K3 board with a green paint for chalk. Want to use them to line my new workshop on the inside. Looking for a method to cut the chalkboards to length and width cheaply as possible. Would like to made one cut metal and K3 AT THE SAME TIME. thank you.

Comment: How many cuts do you need to make?  I ask because "as cheap as possible" does have limits, and some methods will be more durable than others.  Also, how clean do the cuts need to be?  Will the cut metal edge be covered?

Answer (score 2):

A carbide tooth skill saw blade will cut the combination, I use a 70 tooth if i need a really clean cut on thicker metal, but a "finish" blade will work, make sure to wear safety goggles , gloves and a long sleve shirt or coat at some of the chips get thrown.

Comment: That's how I'd do it.  The edge probably won't be pretty - be prepared to finish the edge with a file, flap disk, etc.

Comment: +1, This is exactly what I was thinking, and why I commented about how pretty the edge needs to be.  Of course, use some sort of guide if you need the edge to be straight.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will go with a carbide tooth skill saw blade.